# Is it possible to have C struct as a member of C++ class?

Tags: c++, c, class, struct

let's say I have following plain C struct

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t id;
  uint32_t address;
  uint8_t type;
} Config;

typedef struct
{
  Config cfg; 
  uint32_t ready;
} Instance;
```

My question is whether it is possible to define a C++ class which has an attribute of `Instance` type
i.e.

```
class A
{
    public:
      A();
           
    private:
       Instance instance;   
};
```

If so how the compiler notice that the `Instance` is plain C struct? Is it necessary to use the initialization part of the A class constructor to initialize the `instance`?

Comment: You should read about [Standard Layout Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType).

Comment: In c++ your `Config` and `Instance` are classes like others. Or are they really coming from C? Just asking because a common misunderstanding is that classes declared with `struct` would be fundamentally different from classes declared via `class` in C++

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. How the compiler will notice that it is a plain C struct? Why should it matter? If it does, you can enclose the declaration of the `Instance` struct in a `extern "C" { ... }` block. Is it necessary to use the initialization part... ? It is *possible* to use it if you want to initialize the `instance` member, like for any other member, but it is not *necessary*.

Comment: In C++, `struct` and `class` are synonymous for declaring a type.  The only difference between the two is `struct` has `public` default, and `class` has `private` default.  (For both members and inheritance.)  In C++, both instantiate objects.  They are not treated differently by the language, as contrasted with (say) C# or D, which treat `class` and `struct` differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use the constructor to initialize.
Compiler knows it's a "struct" data type because you defined it that way.
Plain C structures also valid c++ structures so there's nothing called as plain c structure.
Learn more about compilers here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-compiler-explained-what-is-the-compiler-and-how-do-you-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to define structure as attribute of a class. It is better to initialize the all fields of structure in constructor only. You can also use dynamic object of structure

```
    Instance * instance;
    instance = new Instance;
    memset(instance,0,sizeof(Instance));
```

It is always a good practice to initialize all the attributes in constructor, so that you always know what are the default values

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `memset` here is redundant.

Comment: @DanM. Please, would you explan why you think that? I see no constructor setting the simple data type members to anything so I would think they are uninitialized...

Comment: @U.W. Sorry, I misread the second line as `instance = new Instance();` which makes more sense (and doesn't require memset). The current code is correct (if not the best style).